# pyqt adding column at a tableview using QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

I have some problem adding rows at a qtableview using thread for preventing GUI blocking. The number of rows is quite large. (may be 1800 ~ 3000 and each row has graph consisting of large data plot.) So it is simply predicted that Main GUI Thread is block by adding large number of rows if I don't use QThread. Yeah, it is fine so far.

So I implements above to solve the problem that I mentioned, but the problem still remains.

```
class ColumnTableView(MyTableView):
    HistogramColumnNum = 3

    def __init__(self. *args, **kwargs)
        MyTableView.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def beginInsertMode(self, mIdx, sIdx, eIdx):
        self.model().beginResetModel()

    def endInsertMode(self):
        self.model().endResetModel()

        def setData(self, data, ):
        if data is None:
            return
        data = data['outputs']
        keys = list(data.keys())
        try:
            data = data[keys[0]]
        except:
            return
        self.wholeData = data
        model = self.model()
        model.items = []
        self.reset()

        if data is not None:
            dqData = data
            model.beginResetModel()
            model.endResetModel()
            self.worker.requestBeginInsertMode.connect(self.beginInsertMode)
            self.worker.requestEndInsertMode.connect(self.endInsertMode)

            self.worker.setData(data, model)
            self.worker.start()

class Worker(QThread):
    requestBeginInsertMode = pyqtSignal()
    requestEndInsertMode = pyqtSignal()

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.data = None
        self.model = None

    def setData(self, data, model):
        self.model = model
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        data = self.data.npData

        model = self.model
        cols = data.shape[1]

        for idx in range(cols):
            print(idx)
            col = data[:, idx]
            item = Column(str(self.data.header[idx]), str(col.dtype), str(countOmissionData(col)), col)
            model.addColumn(item)
        self.requestEndInsertMode.emit()

class ColumnModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ColumnModel, self).__init__()

    def rowCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
        if not self.items:
            return 0
        else:
            return len(self.items)

    def addColumn(self, column):
        self.items.append(column)
```

So I implements multithread that actually add rows(named Column in my code. Sorry for confusing.) but it is not work (adding column still block the main GUI thread.)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is not safe to perform gui operations outside the main thread, so your current solution will not work. 3000 rows is a trivial amount. The real problem is most likely creating all those graphs. I suggest you do some proper [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) before proceeding any further.

Comment: Thank you for commenting @ekhumoro :)